# Laravel 4 - understanding View::share()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

From what I understand:

```
View::share('foo','bar');
```

Will make $foo available in all views.

However, is it correct to say `View::share()` can be used only in the `__construct()`?

Because from outside `__construct()` I can't make it to work.

Comment: can you put the function on how you've used `View::share()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`View::share` should be available *anywhere* within your application. A common place that it is used is in view composers, but it should be usable within a route or wherever you need it.

Comment: So if I have `View::share('name', 'Steve');` inside a controller's method, $name will be available to all other views? It's just that?

Comment: Ok, I got it wrong initially. I placed in routes.php and it already had the effect I was expecting to. I was trying from inside a single method to another method from another controller.

Comment: just to add something for people looking for a good way to do this... place it inside the ```__construct()``` method of your base controller. ;)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, adding:

```
View::share('foo','bar');
```

in your routes.php file will make $foo (with a value of 'bar') available in all views. This is especially useful for something like Twitter Bootstrap's "active" navigation classes. For example, you could do:

```
View::share('navactive', '');
```

to make sure the navactive variable is set in all views (and thus won't throw errors) and then when you are making views (in your controller, for example), you could pass:

```
return View::make('one')->with('navactive', 'one');
```

and then in your view (preferably some bootstrappy blade template) you can do the following:

```
<ul class="nav">
    @if ( Auth::user() )
    <li @if ($navactive === 'one') class="active" @endif><a href="{{{ URL::to('one/') }}}">One</a></li>
    <li @if ($navactive === 'three') class="active" @endif><a href="{{{ URL::to('three/') }}}">Three</a></li>
    <li @if ($navactive === 'five') class="active" @endif><a href="{{{ URL::to('five/') }}}">Five</a></li>
    @endif
</ul>
```

Comment: That's a handy usage for that. However, you could always add an if statement to check if the `$navactive` `isset()`. Because you've mentioned the navigation marking, another handy solution would be using a plugin that I've built for that very purpose which can be found here: https://github.com/kfirba/markNavigator

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you want to share the variables through all view, you might first want to create a base route(E.x.:`internalController.php`) as a parent class then extend other controllers as a child of it(E.x:`childController.php`).

And yeah you will most likely set the `view::share('foo', $bar)` in the `__constructor()` of the `internalController.php`, since it lunches whenever the class is initialized, this way the parent class will serve the variable values to the child classes.