# Laravel share variable

Tags: jquery-mobile, laravel-4

I have a a few views: mobilepage1, mobilepage2, mobilepage3, mobilepage4 en 5.
First you go to mobilepage1 then hit button "next" and go to mobilepage2 etc.

In mobilepage2 i have a form where the user has to select a few options. Then a controller does a calculation and some variables are shared:

```
View::share('waarschijnlijkheid',$waarschijnlijkheid);
View::share('effect',$effect);
View::share('blootstellingsfreq',$blootstellingsfreq);
View::share('risico',$risico);
```

In mobilepage3 then these variables are displayed and that is done correctly.

After that you get mobilepage 4 and 5. In mobilepage5 i also want to show the same variables again.  I get the error:

```
  {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined variable: waarschijnlijkheid     (View: C:\\Google Drive\\htdocs\\laravel4_test4\\app\\views\\mobilepages\\mobilepage5.blade.php)","file":"C:\\Google Drive\\htdocs\\laravel4_test4\\app\\storage\\views\\49e12d376740da5fc90b17627351022b","line":25}}
```

I read here: [Laravel 4 - understanding View::share()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877948/laravel-4-understanding-viewshare)
that shared variables are accessable troughout the whole application. So why not in my final mobilepage5? Just to test this i made both views exactly the same.

This is the mobilepage5 and 3 snippet.

```
         <td>{{$effect}}</td>
         <td>x</td>
         <td>{{$blootstellingsfreq}}</td>
         <td>x</td>
         <td>{{$waarschijnlijkheid}}</td>
         <td>=</td>
         <td>{{$risico}}</td>
         <td>{{ '->'}}</td>
         <td>{{$risicoklasse}}</td>
```

This is my route file:

```
Route::get('/', function(){

    return View::make('mobilepages.login');
});
Route::post('login','MobileController@login');

Route::get('gotomobilepage1', function()
{
    return View::make('mobilepages.mobilepage1', array('errormessages' => 'no messages'));
});

Route::get('mobilepage2', 'MobileController@save_firstpageform');
Route::post('gotomobilepage3', 'MobileController@save_andcalculaterisc');

Route::post('gotomobilepage4', function(){
      return View::make('mobilepages.mobilepage4');
});
Route::post('gotomobilepage5', 'MobileController@gotomobilepage5function');
```

In my "save_andcalculaterisc" function calculate i share the variables.

```
public function save_andcalculaterisc()
    {         

             $input = Input::all();
             $waarschijnlijkheid = $input['radio_waarschijnlijkheid'];
             $blootstellingsfreq = $input['radio_blootstellingsfreq'];
             $effect = $input['radio_effect'];
             $risico = $blootstellingsfreq*$effect*$waarschijnlijkheid;
             View::share('waarschijnlijkheid',$waarschijnlijkheid);
             View::share('effect',$effect);
             View::share('blootstellingsfreq',$blootstellingsfreq);
             View::share('risico',$risico);

             //$safetyreport = Users::find(1)->safetyreports;

             if($risico<=20){
                $risicoklasse = "Risico wellicht aanvaardbaar: Aandacht dagelijks overleg";

            } else if ($risico>20 && $risico <= 70){
                 $risicoklasse = "Mogelijk risico: Aandacht vereist";
             } else if ($risico>70 && $risico <= 200) {
                  $risicoklasse = "Belangrijk risico: Maatregelen vereist";
               }else if ($risico>200 && $risico <= 400) {
                  $risicoklasse = "Hoog risico: Direct verbetering vereist";
               }else if ($risico >= 400) {
                  $risicoklasse = "Zeer hoog risico: Werkzaamheden stoppen";
               }
               else {
                   $risicoklasse = "Error risicoklasse";
               }
               View::share('risicoklasse',$risicoklasse);
            // }
                 return View::make('mobilepages.mobilepage3');

    }
```

Comment: Where are you putting those `View::share()` commands?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
View::share('waarschijnlijkheid',$waarschijnlijkheid);
View::share('effect',$effect);
View::share('blootstellingsfreq',$blootstellingsfreq);
View::share('risico',$risico);
```

To:

```
View::share(array('risico' => $risico, 'waarschijnlijkheid' => $waarschijnlijkheid, 'effect' => $effect, 'blootstellingsfreq' => $blootstellingsfreq ));
```

I think the issue is that you're using `,` instead of `=>`